# What is Advaita's method of interpretation of Puranas?

Tags: puranas, advaita, adi-shankaracharya

The madhva philosophy as given and follow method of interpretation of Purana. They follow tribhasha and saptabheda .
Do advaita as method of interpretation of Purana ?
Advaita as method of interpretation of Purana means what is that method of interpretation of Purana ? And which scripture tells method of interpretation of Purana ?

Comment: In as much as they are glorified, Puranas are stories nonetheless. Who would want to interpret and write commentaries on Stories? You are mentioning Tribhasha - doesn't it mean Three langages? Saptabheda means seven differences right?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda how is your answer related to question? While saying puranas are smriti you should have explained and answered the question.  This above sentence doesn't suit what the author asked